# SQL query to find new customer IDs on every day that did not exist in the previous day

Tags: mysql, sql

Find new customer_ids for each day in an orders table. This means I want to compare each day with previous days to find the ones existing in that day but not in earlier day.

Table:

| order_id | order_date | customer_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-03-27 | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-03-27 | 2 |
| 3 | 2023-03-27 | 3 |
| 4 | 2023-03-27 | 4 |
| 5 | 2023-03-27 | 5 |
| 6 | 2023-03-28 | 1 |
| 7 | 2023-03-28 | 2 |
| 8 | 2023-03-28 | 6 |
| 9 | 2023-03-28 | 7 |
| 10 | 2023-03-28 | 8 |
| 11 | 2023-03-29 | 7 |
| 12 | 2023-03-29 | 8 |
| 13 | 2023-03-29 | 9 |
| 14 | 2023-03-29 | 10 |
| 15 | 2023-03-29 | 11 |
| 16 | 2023-03-30 | 8 |
| 17 | 2023-03-30 | 9 |
| 18 | 2023-03-30 | 12 |
| 19 | 2023-03-30 | 13 |
| 20 | 2023-03-30 | 14 |

SQL TABLE SCHEMA:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
  order_id INT NOT NULL,
  order_date DATE NOT NULL,
  customer_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (order_id)
);

INSERT INTO orders (order_id, order_date, customer_id)
VALUES
  (1, '2023-03-27', 1),
  (2, '2023-03-27', 2),
  (3, '2023-03-27', 3),
  (4, '2023-03-27', 4),
  (5, '2023-03-27', 5),
  (6, '2023-03-28', 1),
  (7, '2023-03-28', 2),
  (8, '2023-03-28', 6),
  (9, '2023-03-28', 7),
  (10, '2023-03-28', 8),
  (11, '2023-03-29', 7),
  (12, '2023-03-29', 8),
  (13, '2023-03-29', 9),
  (14, '2023-03-29', 10),
  (15, '2023-03-29', 11),
  (16, '2023-03-30', 8),
  (17, '2023-03-30', 9),
  (18, '2023-03-30', 12),
  (19, '2023-03-30', 13),
  (20, '2023-03-30', 14);
```

Note: Could someone please explain this step by step. Thank you in advance!

Just pretty confused with the logic I should follow for the question.

UPDATE 1:
I ran the query below and got the desired results.

```
select * from orders curr
where not exists (
  select 1 
  from orders prev_day 
  where prev_day.order_date = curr.order_date-1 
  and prev_day.customer_id = curr.customer_id
  )
```

I am wondering whether there is also a way to get the same output by a more explicit self-join for a beginner? I tried running only the sub-query and got an error and I am not sure why

Comment: Could you explain what the expected result looks like? Does the query run each day and returns data for that day?

Comment: The query should return the order date and new customer_id. 
order_date customer_id
2023-03-27 1
2023-03-27 2
2023-03-27 3
2023-03-27 4
2023-03-27 5
2023-03-28 6

and so on.

Comment: Please update your question with any additional information, rather than adding it in comments. The approach to solving this is to find records where the order date equals the min order date for each customer

Answer (score 1):

This should be more efficient than a `not exists()` strategy:

```
SELECT order_id, order_date, customer_id
FROM (
    SELECT *,
       LAG(order_date) over (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_date) as prior_date
    FROM orders
) o
WHERE coalesce(DATEDIFF(order_date, prior_date),0) <> 1
```

See it here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/XYBIEPAN

Answer (score 0):

Your query:

```sql
select * from orders curr
where not exists (
  select 1 
  from orders prev_day 
  where prev_day.order_date = curr.order_date-1 
  and prev_day.customer_id = curr.customer_id
  )
```

For every row of table it's selecting `1` (just to check if something exists) from the same table, with same `customer_id`, but `order_date` 1 less then current.

If sub-query finds something, current row drops from dataset. If it finds nothing (hence `NOT EXISTS`) current row is added to result dataset.

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ueivlw5Q).

Comment: Hello, this is perfect! Is there also a way to get the same output by a more explicit self-join for a beginner?  I tried running the sub query and got an error

Answer (score 0):

If you think about this problem in a different way, all you need is to find the records that customers placed their first order.

So here it is:

```sql
select *
from orders
group by customer_id
having order_date = min(order_date);
```